# Problemas para hacer deploy en QWIK con firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, hosting, qwik

Quiero mandar mi app a producción con firebase hosting, pero tengo problemas al hacer el build de la app. En la documentacíon me pide correr el siguiente comando "npm run qwik add firebase", eso me generó varios archivos, uno de ellos una carpeta llamada functions que despues me pide instalar paquetes con los comandos "cd functions" y "npm i", lo hice y todo bien. Después me pide hacer el build con el comando "npm run build" empieza a crearlo, pero despues en consola me aparece este mensaje en color verde: **Starting Qwik City SSG...** y despues el error justo debajo

```
node:fs:1513
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'src/content/post'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1513:3)
    at load (file:///C:/Users/NET99/Desktop/ProjectNewNet99/net99/functions/server/assets/@qwik-city-plan-ad098a3f.mjs:12091:22)    at fetchPosts (file:///C:/Users/NET99/Desktop/ProjectNewNet99/net99/functions/server/assets/@qwik-city-plan-ad098a3f.mjs:12099:23)
    at Module.onStaticGenerate (file:///C:/Users/NET99/Desktop/ProjectNewNet99/net99/functions/server/assets/@qwik-city-plan-ad098a3f.mjs:22684:23)
```

No sé que me falte hacer, ya intenté reinstalando las dependencias y limpiando caché del npm.